# R.java generates incorrectly in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

In working on my current project, I am attempting to make a basic browser for Flickr, and I have been trying to use the recycler_view as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    activateToolbar();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ProcessPhotos processPhotos = new ProcessPhotos("android, lollipop", true);
    processPhotos.execute();
}
```

The project did not list any errors until I attempted to run it, at which time Android Studio identifies an error in R.java line 2655, where the file repeatedly generates as

```
        public static final int recycler view=0x7f0c006b;
```

which is obviously a problem because the correct name for it is recycler_view, and the lack of an underscore prevents the whole deal from launching.

What I've tried:

1. Cleaning the project.
2. Rebuilding the project.
3. Relaunching Android Studio.
4. Invalidating the cache and restarting.
5. Checking XML files for obvious (to my beginner's eyes) or identified errors.
6. Changing the dependencies in the app gradle from

   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.+'

   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+'

   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.+'

   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.+'

   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.+'

to specific version references.

Comment: `public static final int recycler view=0x7f0c006b;` You can't have a space. `recycler view` is an invalid name.

Comment: It reformats to the invalid name automatically.

Comment: What if you try another name? i.e.: `vw_recycler`

Comment: R.java still becomes a problem because it compiles back to an invalid name. My changes to R.java are undone every time Android Studio starts, and even if I change the recycler use to the name on R.java, it fails to launch because R.java continually regenerates to said deficient code.

Comment: `My changes to R.java` You must **not touch** the R.java file manually!! The modifies have to be done to the xml files **only**!!.

Comment: The error occurred before, during and after.

Comment: I would say there is something wrong with your activity_main layout.

Comment: Try by changing recycler view id name

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I had a similar problem, not the same), and run.

Add this in your `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-dontshrink
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have fixed it, but I really appreciate the help.